# Google App Engine Python 2.7 tutorial Error

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am following Google App Engine "Hello world" tutorial in this link: 
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/helloworld

I want to load my helloworld.py application:

```
import webapp2

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
      self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
      self.response.out.write('Hello, Udacity!')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)],
                              debug=True)
```

And I set the yaml file:

```
application: helloworld
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: helloworld.app
```

I am not using Google App Engine Launcher, just want to do everything in the console or command line.

I want to start my helloworld app using `dev_appserver.py --port=8888 helloworld`, but the console complains `AppConfigNotFoundError`. The console outputs

```
C:\Documents and Settings\XXX\Desktop\helloworld>dev_appserver.py --port=8888
 helloworld
WARNING  2012-08-11 23:12:21,562 rdbms_mysqldb.py:74] The rdbms API is not avail
able because the MySQLdb library could not be loaded.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py", line 1
33, in <module>
    run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py", line 1
29, in run_file
    execfile(script_path, globals_)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\de
v_appserver_main.py", line 694, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\de
v_appserver_main.py", line 582, in main
    root_path, {}, default_partition=default_partition)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\de
v_appserver.py", line 3217, in LoadAppConfig
    raise AppConfigNotFoundError
google.appengine.tools.dev_appserver.AppConfigNotFoundError
```

Would this be a path problem? My `helloworld.py` and `app.yaml` is in a folder on my desktop and not in the google app engine directory.

How can fix this error? Any suggestion is appreciated!

Note: I am using Python 2.7 **NOT** 2.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `dev_appserver.py`, the last argument should be the path to the directory that your app.yaml is in. In your case, since you are running from within your project's directory, you can just use `dev_appserver.py --port=8888 .`, because `.` is short for the current directory.